# Domain rich applications without ORMs

Tags: database-design, orm, domain-driven-design, oop

I am relatively new to the world of software development. I am currently on a project, which is quite large, and it's decent OO code - mostly following Domain Driven Design principles. However, often while this sounds great in theory, practically the whole Object Relational Impedance is pretty bad, and it means some parts of the system are quite slow using just the ORM layer, unless we write optimised SQL queries to cover those cases. Also, sometimes we seem to be stuck trying to see whether we should model the domain based on SQL's performance vs OO principles.

This makes me ask this - is this the way most applications are built? Meaning - yes, OO is well and good - but I find it hard to believe that with all the problems associated with this Object relational mismatch, is this the best way to build apps? The alternative approach I can think of is to ditch the ORMs and just have domain modelling, and writing native SQL queries directly by hand uniformly. I would like to know if there are actually software systems of sufficient size being built this way.

I am sorry if I sound n00bish - but I am new and would like to know what other approaches are there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can use both.

To be honest, for simple single record modifications and views (including display of related entities), the ORM generates pretty much the same code as I would write by hand. So the advantage is of course that I **don't** have to write it. Plus, minor schema modifications are handled gracefully.

For everything else, plain SQL is king.

I'm of the opinion that any code that **can** be generated, **should** be generated, as long as it doesn't produce a clearly substandard version. I think this is my key point: *A significant amount of an application's database code, can be delt with by an ORM and still perform equally well as hand crafted sql code written by a database expert.*

Comment: +1 for fact that single-row ops are about the same, and the comment that I absolutely never hear, and began to think I was the only person who believed it, that any code that can be generated should be generated.  However, I don't agree that the ORM generated code works as well, usually because of the bletcherous table designs you get from modeling on OO ideas instead of relational.  But still worth a +1

Comment: +1 for the "any code that can be generated should be generated" statement.  I'd perhaps suffix it with "well" - i.e. not just generate code, generate _good_ code.  But the principle stands.

Comment: @Ken Downs, that would be a problem with the design, and not with the ORM itself. But I get your point, and fully agree.

Answer (score 3):

Don't apologize for recognizing the obvious.  Those with far more experience often utterly fail to recognize what you have: ORM is bad engineering, for exactly the reasons you specify.

But I don't want to descend into a rant.  The arguments against using embedded SQL range from stylistic, "i don't want that garbage in my code" to, um, stylistic, "SQL is ugly."  But it works, it's fast, and it's good engineering.

Comment: having worked with both ORM's and plain SQL + JDBC/ibatis, i still prefer to write my queries or even better, have my DBA optimize my queries, those arguments sounds more like excuses to not learn (propper) SQL

Comment: Actually using ORM doesn not mean you don't have control over the generate SQL or you don't have to have a good DB design. Moreover, if you need special skills to write SQL queries it usually means that your DB schema is broken. The schema should make the most frequent queries easy to write (and fast to execute). When I use ORM I create my schema in such a way that queries generated by my ORM are simple and fast. It is not rocket science.

Comment: so if an schema its not easily usable from an ORM, the schema is broken?, i dont agree, there can be a number of reasons of why the schema would be diffiult to use with an ORM, usually an schema is designed to meet the bussiness's needs, not an ORM's performance needs, and if i have to design my schema so my ORM is happy and fast, now that is broken

Comment: To be fair, there are other reasons for resistance to embedded SQL.  (1) it's often embedded as strings so prone to error; (2) SQL is a different language founded on a different model.  Not to say those are defensible: some IDEs now do a better job with (1), and any half-serious developer needs to learn SQL anyway.  But they are nevertheless significant factors.

Comment: There should be lots of studies that quantify just how bad engineering ORMs really are compared to SQL.  Could you link in some real world realistic studies that have detailed numbers on the performance hits?